# Getting same error over and over again on the method No overload for method 'CopyToAsync' takes 4 arguments , how to resolve it?

Tags: c#

The exception is at line number 50:

```
await response.Content.CopyToAsync(destination, 81920, progressWrapper, cancellationToken);
```

and the method code:  I see the method should get 5 parameters not 4 but not sure what the last parameters I should put in the await in line 50.

```
static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize, IProgress<DownloadProgress> progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (bufferSize < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize));
    if (source is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (!source.CanRead)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(source)}' is not readable.");
    if (destination == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
    if (!destination.CanWrite)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(destination)}' is not writable.");

    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    long totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
    {
        await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

        // Report progress with the downloaded size
        progress?.Report(new DownloadProgress
        {
            ProgressPercentage = (float)(totalBytesRead / (float)source.Length) * 100,
            DownloadedSize = totalBytesRead,
            ContentLength = source.Length
        });
    }
}
```

full code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

public static class HttpClientProgressExtensions
{
    public static async Task DownloadDataAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUrl, Stream destination, IProgress<DownloadProgress> progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (client is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestUrl))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(requestUrl)}' cannot be null or empty.", nameof(requestUrl));
        }

        if (destination is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
        }

        if (progress is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(progress));
        }

        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
            using (var download = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                // no progress... no contentLength... very sad
                if (progress is null || !contentLength.HasValue)
                {
                    await download.CopyToAsync(destination);
                    return;
                }
                // Such progress and contentLength much reporting Wow!
                var progressWrapper = new Progress<long>(totalBytes => progress.Report(new DownloadProgress
                {
                    ProgressPercentage = GetProgressPercentage(totalBytes, contentLength.Value),
                    ContentLength = contentLength.Value
                }));
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(destination, 81920, progressWrapper, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        float GetProgressPercentage(float totalBytes, float currentBytes) => (totalBytes / currentBytes) * 100f;
    }

    static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize, IProgress<DownloadProgress> progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (bufferSize < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize));
        if (source is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (!source.CanRead)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(source)}' is not readable.");
        if (destination == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
        if (!destination.CanWrite)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(destination)}' is not writable.");

        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
        {
            await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            // Report progress with the downloaded size
            progress?.Report(new DownloadProgress
            {
                ProgressPercentage = (float)(totalBytesRead / (float)source.Length) * 100,
                DownloadedSize = totalBytesRead,
                ContentLength = source.Length
            });
        }
    }

    public class DownloadProgress
    {
        public float ProgressPercentage { get; set; }
        public long ContentLength { get; set; }
        public long DownloadedSize { get; set; } // Add this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `await download.CopyToAsync(destination, 81920, progressWrapper, cancellationToken);`?

Comment: what namespace is the class that defines your `CopyToAsync` located in? does the code that *uses* the method have a `using ThatNamespace;` directive? extension methods are in scope only if their containing type is in scope

Comment: [Stream.CopyToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=net-8.0) is a built-in method that *doesn't* accept 4 parameters. Your own `static async Task CopyToAsync` is a *private* method so it's not visible in `DownloadDataAsync` so the built-in method will be chosen. Make your extension method `internal` or `public`